# Why does my local storage item appear to be defined when it isn't?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to insert an empty array into localStorage if item doesn't exist:

```
    static getLocalActivities(){
        var localActivities = localStorage.getItem("Local-Activities");
        if (localActivities === undefined){
            LocalStorageFunctions.createLocalActivities()
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Local-Activities"))
        }
        else{
            if (localActivities.length === 0){return localActivities}
            else{
                // return JSON.parse(localActivities) // fails because not empty arr
                return localActivities;
            }
        }
    }
    static createLocalActivities(){
        return localStorage.setItem('Local-Activities', []); // < this doesnt work
        // return localStorage.setItem('Local-Activities', JSON.stringify([])); // < this doesnt work
    }
```

both methods for creating the item always in application chrome tools show:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

1. This `var localActivities = localStorage.getItem("Local-Activities");` returns `'undefined'` and not `undefined` - take notice that the first one is a string.
2. This if is always false `if (localActivities === undefined){` because `localActivities` is `'undefined'` not `undefined`
3. Hence `createLocalActivities` never runs

### Solution

1. Clear the localStorage value from the dev tools
2. Use `JSON.stringify` to save values as suggested in the comments

Comment: There is two version, one is commented out to test the other, both return the same result.

Also it does run, I have repeatedly tested by deleting the data in localStorage

Comment: Neither of the two `setItem` in your code will result in `undefined` so you have to have a third place where you set the item to undefined.

Comment: My Apologies, I had a parent component interacting & overwriting localStorage and content. Your answer is correct, undefined does not work and the setitem method you mentioned works fine. Cheers